# HtmlEncode UTF-8

Tags: unicode, asp-classic, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm using Server.HtmlEncode on a utf-8 string in asp-classic, which works fine until there are some accents in the string e.g. Rüstü Recber, which appears as RÃ¼stÃ¼ Recber (R&#195;&#188;st&#195;&#188; Recber in the source).

I've tried setting the Response.Charset property to utf-8 but this doesn't make any difference.

Comment: Now you've solved it, you might want to supply your solution as an answer and mark it as Answered. Then this question wont come up in the Unanswered list anymore. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update (Solved): Adding <%@CODEPAGE=65001%> at the start of the page corrected the problem (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742422.aspx)

Many thanks for all of the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the editor you are using to view the text is set to show utf-8.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to UrlEncode as well?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the string is correct before it is passed to HtmlEncode ? It looks like the string might be encoded wrong *before* it is passed to HtmlEncode.

Try to encode a string that you know is correct, and see if it is encoded correctly.