# Additional Ascii char 'Â' added in JSP request

Tags: java, jsp, httprequest, extended-ascii

I am facing the same issue in tomcat & jsp as listed in below asp issue
[Classic ASP gremlims, getting a Â inserted into text whenever an HTML special character is used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/350429/classic-asp-gremlims-getting-a-ainserted-into-text-whenever-an-html-special-cha)

Using tomcat 5 and jsp. When I type in a string containing like ±20°C and submit to another JSP the resultant parameter after submit is Â±20Â°C. An addition character 'Â' is being added before every special char in the request itself. How do I resolve this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: If it's the same issue, why are you opening a new question?

Answer (score 6):

This is caused by displaying UTF-8 page as Latin-1. For example, ± is encoded as 0xB1 in Latin-1 but 0xC2, 0xB1 in UTF-8. 0xC2 happens to be Â.

This is kind of strange for a JSP page. Normally, JSP will use the same encoding in the writer and "Content-Type" header so you always get the same encoding. Check if you specifies encoding like this,

```
<%@page pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
```

If you have a custom "Content-Type" header, make sure you append ", charset=UTF-8".

Answer (score 1):

That is the symptom of ISO-Latin-whatever source data being transcoded into UTF-8 on the way out.  Check your character encodings.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<%@ page pageEncoding="utf-8" %>
```

and

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, which seems to now be fixed after altering the following <meta> line in the <head> block.

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

It's the utf-8 which is important!

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

To the point: during each step where `byte`-`char` conversion is involved, you need to specify the same and correct character encoding everywhere. To cover any human character at the world, `UTF-8` is a perfect choice.

There are several steps you need to specify this character encoding: parsing `GET` query parameters (configureable in appserver settings), parsing `POST` request body (configureable with help of a Filter), writing to the response stream (configurable with help of `@page pageEncoding` in JSP or `HttpServletResponse#setCharacterEncoding()` in Servlet), reading/writing to database (configureable in DB table itself), reading/writing to files (configureable using `InputStreamReader` and `OutputStreamWriter`).

You can find more detailed background information and complete code solutions in [this article](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html).

Hope this helps.