# getting post variables in asp with non-alphanumeric fieldnames

Tags: forms, asp-classic

I am working with a legacy form builder system that can have non-alphanumeric fieldnames
so for example

```
< input type=text name="5-Teléfono">
```

and in asp, simply doing the following will not output the posted value

```
response.write (request('5-Teléfono'))
```

I understand this isn't the best design decision (should probably name the fields text_123 ... etc), however updating the whole system to use this structure would take time.

Is there a way in asp for me to read form field names with non-alphanumerics ?

Comment: What browser? Have you set [`Response.Charset`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525304%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) and [`@CODEPAGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524967%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)? See [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/352393/249624) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
response.write (request("5-Teléfono"))
```

(ie with double quotes around 5-Teléfono)

Single quotes in vbscript are used to comment out what comes afterwards

Comment: Thanks John, that was a mistake when I was typing in my question.
Through some testing, it looks like the field is converted to "5-TelÃ©fono" instead of 5-Teléfono .. .which seems to be causing the error ... any idea how I can get this resovled ?

Comment: Open all the relevant files in Notepad. Select Save As from the File menu and if the encoding dropdown is set to ANSI then change it to UTF-8.  It might also be a good idea to add a meta charset=utf-8 tag in your form page.  I've tested this and it works

Answer (score 0):

Don't use such names, it's like using non English variable names - same impact.

If you can't change the name, you can still iterate the posted values and look for the proper one:

```
For Each key In Request.Form
    If (InStr(key, "fono") > 0) And (InStr(key, "5-Tel") > 0) Then
        Response.Write("Found, value is: " & Request.Form(key))
    End If
Next
```